# How to detect the last slide and first slide in slick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to detect the first slide and last slide using slick.js.https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want to do when you detect that. Provide a bit more info. What the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is couple of events you can use to detect this:

beforeChange

```
$('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log(nextSlide);
});
```

afterChange

```
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
  console.log(currentSlide);
});
```

swipe

```
$('.slider').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
  console.log(direction);
  // left
});
```

Let me know if this works for u.

Thanks